# angular2-webpack-starter start from a static page

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using angular2-webpack-starter to start my project. This project will initially load index.html and we can build our own component or any other things based on that. However, in my case I want first go to a static page without any angular code and then we can click button and redirect me to a page where angular code loads.

So basically the path should be index.html(static page) --> click a button --> app.html(the first page that angular loads).

I tried to add my root tag in app.html but it just didn't show up. Seems like app.html cannot recognized that tag.

Do I need to do something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to start the angular with the static html. Its a matter of deployment. Call it index.html and setup your selected server. I think its default behavior to go to that page. 
ex: http:/youserverlocation/yourapp  ---> index.html with you button (you will need basic javascript for this, or use bootstrap and style an achor link as a button)
   http:/youserverlocation/yourapp/#/angularroute ---> will be caugt by the angular router